# What is the equivalent of update-modules in CentOS 6.4?

Tags: centos, kernel-modules, modprobe

I am adding files to `/etc/modprobe.d`, and a README of some software that I'm installing advised to run `update-modules` afterwards.

```
$ sudo update-modules
-bash: update-modules: command not found
```

What is the equivalent of this program in CentOS 6.4? Or is `update-modules` deprecated? What is the new program called?

Comment: Did you try `sudo yum update`

Comment: @Ketan, I don't have my Linux system right now. I am installing this software manually. It's not in any public repository. What does `yum update` have to do with the modules governed by modprobe?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question.

Answer (score 0):

the update-modules command has been deprecated for some time. The equivalent is:

`depmod -a`